# @Controller doesn't work when @RestController exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Because of some reason, my project has to use both @Controller and @RestController and the @RestController has `api` prefix. But when I access to urls belonged to @Controller, It's return 404 page and root page without `api` prefix return: 
[image: root page] Can't @RestController and @Controller stand together?

**Controller.java**

```
 @Controller
public class HomeController {

  private final CourseRepository courseRepository;

  @Autowired
  public HomeController(CourseRepository courseRepository) {
    this.courseRepository = courseRepository;
  }

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("courses", courseRepository.findAll());
    return "home";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/hello")
  public String hello() {
    return "hello";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/login")
  public String login() {
    return "login";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/403")
  public String error() {
    return "403";
  }
}
```

**RestController.java**

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestController {

  private final UserRolesRepository userRolesRepository;
  private final CourseRepository courseRepository;

  @Autowired
  public RestController(UserRolesRepository userRolesRepository, CourseRepository courseRepository) {
    this.userRolesRepository = userRolesRepository;
    this.courseRepository = courseRepository;
  }

  @RequestMapping("/courses")
  List<Course> readCourses() {
    return courseRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: Tell us more about those `Controller` and `RestController`s by posting more code

Comment: The `/` result is because of Spring Data REST. Are sure that your `ViewResolver` configured properly? Post your `ViewResolver` configuration and project structure

Comment: tell me more about your code? are you using spring data? spring data rest?

Comment: I"m using spring-data-jpa and thymeleaf for víew. So there no view resolver right? I just return view name in the controller and match them with files in templates folder. I can't update my code now. Maybe next 7 or 8 hours

Comment: After I restart my IDE (IntellIJ), It worked correctly. It's so weird